# Why java.nio.ByteBuffer changes when sending via Thrift?

Tags: java, scala, thrift, bytebuffer

I was writing a Thrift api with a request contains binary data in Scala.

The contract was like this:

```
struct Request {
  10: required string name
  20: required binary data
  30: required string type
}
```

The ByteBuffer object in client before sending was like this:

```
java.nio.HeapByteBufferR[pos=0 lim=4 cap=4]
```

However, the ByteBuffer object received by the server was different:

```
java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=230 lim=234 cap=312]
```

My question is why does this happen? And what are the best practices to not accidentally change the ByteBuffer?

Comment: Is the buffer received by the server supposed to be _your_ buffer and your buffer _only_? Because the buffer on the server end has a `pos=230` and `lim=234`, meaning it has `4` bytes ready to be read, which appears to match your client-side buffer. Perhaps the server-side buffer contains other information, such as a protocol header, and is simply _positioned_ to read the data you sent (and only that data). Note it may help others help you if you provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

This is because the ByteBuffer in the server side will wrap all the information of the request and set the pos and limit to the partition that contains the binary data. So to get only the binary data part, simply use the slice method of ByteBuffer.